# unable to switch to GUI mode of my Ubuntu 22.04. LTS even after attempting to update, upgadre, ubuntu-desktop, slim etc

Tags: command-line, gui

I am unable to switch to the GUI mode of my Ubuntu 22.04. LTS even after attempting to update, upgrade, ubuntu-desktop, slim, etc. In the command-line interface, ctrl+ALt+F7 is also not working. In Ctrl+Alt+F1 mode, whatever updates and upgrades were required, I did everything, but the reboot again led to me in the tty1 mode only.